# Determine length of time keys are pressed

Tags: time, autohotkey

Can below script be modified so that the keys
"cl" fires "www.google.com" just if the "cl" keys
are both pressed for 500 milliseconds ?

Reason for this is that as part typing text sometimes the keys "cl" are pressed in rapid succession which then fires "www.google.com"

```
~l::
If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Send, {Backspace Down}{Backspace Up}{Backspace Down}{Backspace Up}
    Run, "www.google.com"
}
Return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `A_TickCount` may be a good option.

```
~l::
    duration := 0
    If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) 
    {
        start := A_TickCount
        While (GetKeyState("c") && GetKeyState("l"))
            Sleep, 1
        duration := A_TickCount - start

    }
    if (duration > 500)
        Run, "www.google.com"
    Return
```

Comment: thanks but im leaning towards accepting my own answer as I think its easier to understand and has been working for me with no issue for past day now... but if there is some issue with my code or if there are advantages to using your script above then please let me know.

Comment: The only clear advantage to my solution would be that you could have the keys perform different actions based up the time the keys are held. ie. if held for over a second, do something else. A `KeyWait` could also be used if you want to avoid the keys c and l being sent when both held.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do the trick :

```
~c::
~l::
If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Send, {Backspace Down}{Backspace Up}{Backspace Down}{Backspace Up}

    sleep, 100

    If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    Run, "www.google.com"
    }

    Return

}
Return
```

Comment: The accepted answer works if you want something to run **On Release** but this one evaluates after 100 ms no matter, better for gaming purposes! +1

Answer (score 0):

Per [this AutoHotKey forum post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/467-record-key-press-duration/):

> [T]he only way to program a key down for a specific duration is to use the down command and then a wait function with a (manually entered time) and then the up command[.]

So, you could solve this problem by putting a timer and then another if block inside your current if block, although it sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 millisecond delay could  cause uncontrolled key repetition sothat we can't reliably delete the pressed keys anymore. So my suggestion is to find the repeat delay and only wait for so long minus ~150 milliseconds:

```
~c::
~l::
If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
    If (!GetKeyState("c","p") || !GetKeyState("l","p"))
        Return
    DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt, 0x16, UInt, 0, UIntP, RepeatDelay, UInt, 0) ;get the key repeat delay
    Sleep % (RepeatDelay+1)*250-150
    If (GetKeyState("c","p") && GetKeyState("l","p")) {
        SendInput, {c up}{l up}{BS}{BS}
        Run, www.google.com
    }
}
Return
```

[SystemParametersInfo - SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx#SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY)